# Confidence Intervals around Backtransformed Log-linear Regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, back-transformation

Suppose we are interested in the percentage effect of a binary $D \in \{0,1\}$ on an outcome $Y \in \mathbb{R}$, which might motivate a simple regression of the form:
$$ \log Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D + \epsilon $$
Since $\beta_1$ may be interpreted as the marginal effect of $D$ on $\log Y$ (which is not very helpful), we might wish to consider inference on $e^{\beta_1}$ which represents a multiplicative factor - i.e. if $D=1$, then we expect the outcome to change by a factor of $e^{\beta_1}$, or a percentage change of $100 * (e^{\beta_1}-1)$.

---

Now suppose we know that
$$ \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_1 - \beta_1) \to^d \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2) $$
By the Delta Method, this implies
$$ \sqrt{n}(e^{\hat{\beta}_1} - e^{\beta_1}) \to^d \mathcal{N}(0, e^{2\beta_1}\sigma^2) $$
Thus confidence intervals for $e^{\beta_1}$ at a $\alpha=0.05$ significance level may be obtained by
$$ 
\Big[ \frac{ e^{\hat{\beta}_1} }{ 1+\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}z_{1-\alpha/2} }, \frac{ e^{\hat{\beta}_1} }{ 1+\frac{\hat{\sigma}}{\sqrt{n}}z_{\alpha/2} } \Big] 
$$
where $z$ are the critical values from the quantile of a standard normal.

Would someone mind checking this calculation? It looks a bit strange as it is asymmetric, but perhaps that's just the nature of the log-exp transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indeed arrive at an expression that looks different.

From
$$ \sqrt{n}(e^{\hat{\beta}_1} - e^{\beta_1}) \to^d \mathcal{N}(0, e^{2\beta_1}\sigma^2) $$
we obtain, plugging in the estimator for $\beta_1$ in the denominator and using Slutzky's theorem,
$$
P\left(z_{\alpha/2}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}(e^{\hat{\beta}_1} - e^{\beta_1})}{\sqrt{e^{2\hat\beta_1}\hat\sigma^2}}\leq z_{1-\alpha/2}\right)\to 1-\alpha
$$
or
$$
P\left(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}e^{\hat\beta_1}\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}-e^{\hat{\beta}_1}\leq  - e^{\beta_1}\leq \frac{e^{\hat\beta_1}\hat\sigma z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}-e^{\hat{\beta}_1}\right)\to 1-\alpha
$$
or
$$
P\left(e^{\hat{\beta}_1}-\frac{z_{\alpha/2}e^{\hat\beta_1}\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\geq  e^{\beta_1}\geq e^{\hat{\beta}_1}-\frac{e^{\hat\beta_1}\hat\sigma z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\to 1-\alpha,
$$
such that the confidence interval would become
$$
\left(e^{\hat{\beta}_1}\left[1-\frac{\hat\sigma z_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\right];e^{\hat{\beta}_1}\left[1-\frac{z_{\alpha/2}\hat\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\right)
$$

Comment: Ah I had accidentally wrote the denominator in the second step as $\sqrt{e^{2\beta_1 \hat{\sigma}^2}}$! Forgot the hats :)